Using RealVNC to edit code on a Raspberry Pi 5 causes repeating characters
When connected to my Raspberry PI 5 from my Windows 11 pc using RealVNC, I get lots of unwanted characters appearing, these are mainly 0s 9s and brackets, i.e. when I'm trying to type something like the following (into either VS Code or Geanny)
def myFunc()
it will instead keep repeating the initial bracket
def myFunc((((((((((((((((((((((((((((((((((((
The bracket key (i.e. shift 9) often doesn't work either, and I sometimes have to press is multiple times to get the opening bracket to appear.. then it will often repeat (without me holding down the key)
I don't know if this is an issue with the PI, my Windows machine, or RealVNC.
My RasPI OS is Linux raspberrypi 6.6.20+rpt-rpi-2712 #1 SMP PREEMPT Debian 1:6.6.20-1+rpt1 (2024-03-07) aarch64
My RealVNC version (Windows) is 7.10.0 (r52294) - Feb 21st 2024
On PI - realvnc-vnc-server/stable,now 7.5.1.50075 arm64
Both Windows and Linux have all the latest updates installed, and I have no issues with my local Windows computer.
--- UPDATE ---
If found that if I type sudo lsof -iTCP it shows that wayvnc is listening on port 5900, and RealVNC isn't. I followed the instructions on this page (to try to disable it)
https://help.realvnc.com/hc/en-us/articles/4417193011857-How-do-I-disable-Wayland-to-use-RealVNC-Connect#ubuntu-0-3
But it still shows wayvnc listening (also after reboot)

??? You said, "I followed the instructions on this page (to try to disable it)". If you did follow the instructions (i.e. disable Wayland in favor of X) I wonder why Wayland is even running? Did your desktop switch over to the X desktop?

@Seamus I think my configuration of VNC was/is a bit messed up. I tried to disable WayVNC using the option mentioned, and eventually got it removed (by using an interface option) I also managed to get RealVNC installed, and working, but it seems to have issues with the speed, it's really laggy in VSCode and Geany now. I'm considering re-installing PI OS to see if it works if I start from fresh.

I wish I had a better option for you... I run all my systems headless, so I know very little about this "GUI stuff". Sometimes starting with a clean slate is the best approach. If you can, consider using raspi-config first to do the 'switch' fm Wayland to X. Then, check that out before installing realVNC.
